# C++ Concepts Same and Assignable

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I have been experimenting with C++ concepts recently. I am trying the definitions from the following Ranges Extensions document:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4569.pdf

The definitions and usages of `Same` are confusing me. For reasons unknown to me, the authors did not give an explicit definition. So I am using:

```
template <class T, class U>
concept bool Same()
{
  return std::is_same<T, U>::value;
}
```

The problem is that the document gives the following definition for `Assignable`:

```
template <class T, class U>
concept bool Assignable()
{
  return Common<T, U>() && requires(T&& a, U&& b) {
    { std::forward<T>(a) = std::forward<U>(b) } -> Same<T&>;
  };
}
```

It does not work (under GCC 6.3): a simple `Assignable<int&, int&&>()` concept check gives me `false` (I have verified that the `Common` part is OK). I have to change `Same<T&>` to `T&` to make it seemingly work. The same `Same<Type>` check is used in some other places too.

My questions are:

- Is my definition of `Same` correct?
- Why is `Same<T&>` used instead of `T&`? What are the differences?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After attacking the problem during the weekend, I think I have found the answer myself.

Eric Niebler and Casey Carter have a more refined definition of `Same` that supports multiple template arguments (not just two), but my definition should be basically right for the two-argument case.

When using `-> Type`, the purpose is that the expression in the brackets can be implicitly converted to `Type`. When using `-> Same<Type>`, the purpose is that the expression in the brackets is exactly `Type`. So they are different.

However, there is a gotcha. The constraint check is quite complicated, and even experts like Eric and Casey made a mistake and gave wrong definitions in N4569. Eric discussed the issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/ericniebler/stl2/issues/330

When used the way it was given in N4569, it means the expression should be able to be passed to an imagined function template like

```
template <typename U>
f(U)
requires Same<T&, U>()
```

This doesn't work—if the expression passed in is an lvalue of `T`, the deduced `U` is `T` instead of `T&`. The solution is use `Same<T&>&&` in `Assignable`. It will result in the following imagined function template:

```
template <typename U>
f(U&&)
requires Same<T&, U>()
```

Now everything is OK—if the expression passed in is an lvalue of `T`, `U` has to be deduced as `T&`.

Playing with concepts is a good practice for me, but I probably should find their code earlier. They have a complete set of concepts in the following GitHub repository:

https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2

People interested in C++ concepts should look into it.

Comment: The issue with the definition of `Same` is a bit more subtle: the Ranges TS requires implementations to treat the constraint `Same<T, U>()` as equivalent to `Same<U, T>()`. This is not possible with any simple definition. It can't be expressed in the language, and effectively requires implementation of `Same` via a compiler intrinsic.

Comment: You are completely correct in your assessment of the problem exemplified in `Assignable`: deduction constraints were broken in GCC while I was implementing cmcstl2, and I subtly misinterpreted the semantics in developing a workaround syntax that was almost-equivalent. Consequently, we didn't realize the concept definitions in the TS were broken until recently.

Comment: @Casey I would actually argue your bug is more the failure of the current concepts proposal. Using `Same<T&>&&` looks ugly and not intuitive at all.

Comment: @Casey Would you please elaborate when my definition (based on `std::is_same`) will fail while an intrinsic-based one won't? It sounds intriguing.

Comment: Elaborated in an additional answer.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with the definition of `Same` is a bit more subtle: the Ranges TS requires implementations to treat the constraint `Same<T, U>()` as equivalent to `Same<U, T>()`, i.e., recognize the symmetry of "`T` is the same type as `U`":

```
template <class T, class U>
requires Same<T, U>()
void foo(); // #1

template <class T, class U>
requires Same<U, T>()
void foo(); // redeclaration of #1

template <class T>
requires Same<int, T>()
void bar(); // #2

template <class T>
requires Same<T, int>()
void bar(); // redeclaration of #2
```

This equivalence can't be expressed in the language, since the rules for normalization of constraints recognize each of:

```
is_same_v<T, U>
is_same_v<U, T>
is_same_v<T, int>
is_same_v<int, T>
```

as distinct atomic constraints. This requires implementation of `Same` via a compiler intrinsic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have a real-world or contrived case where the difference leads to problems? Sorry, I just could not figure it out.

Comment: I know no real-world examples where constraining generic code naturally leads to cases like this. Andrew Sutton may know of some? IIRC the original suggestion for this requirement came from him.