# Ranges TS: Same concept differs from std::is_same?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts

I was browsing through the [Ranges TS documentation on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges), and in the entry for the `Same` concept, I came across this sentence:

> For the purposes of constraint checking, `Same<T, U>()` implies `Same<U, T>()`.

and a note:

> The additional requirement on constraint checking differentiates `Same` from `std::is_same`, and will typically require a compiler intrinsic to implement.

This struck me as a little odd, so I decided to check the [Ranges TS paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4651.pdf), and sure enough, it says:

> Remarks: For the purposes of constraint checking, `Same<T, U>()` implies `Same<U, T>()`.

(However, Casey Carter's STL2 implementation [does use `std::is_same`](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2/blob/83abdc9781bab0ca14469df32ac092c42be56140/include/meta/meta_fwd.hpp#L71), perhaps because the required compiler intrinsic doesn't yet exist.)

So my question is, what exactly does the requirement "`Same<T, U>()` implies `Same<U, T>()`" actually mean? How would it be possible for `std::is_same<T, U>` to differ from `std::is_same<U, T>`?

Comment: [May be related](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

Comment: The question isn't an exact duplicate, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42956674/923854) explains exactly this weirdness with `Same`. Also you linked to the definition of `meta::Same` in cmcstl2, which is not the same (pun intended) concept as [`std::experimental::ranges::Same`](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2/blob/83abdc9781bab0ca14469df32ac092c42be56140/include/stl2/detail/concepts/core.hpp#L57) which *does* use a compiler intrinsic, albeit one that I think does not fully implement the desired semantics.

Comment: @Casey Thanks! :